# yesod on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, haskell

using Ubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo E135, I've installed the Haskell package and the yesod helper package via Ubuntu Software Center. Installation was success. But if I want to create an Yesod project with "yesod init" and "yesod devel" as provided in the Quick start guid at yesod web site, this failed. Error message told something about "cabal install failed during configuration step on library xy... ExitCode 1" which caused some dependencies to be unresolved but needed for the yesod project to compile.

I've tried also to install Haskell via Ubuntu Software center and yesod via cabal with the same result (but different libraries indicated in the error Message).

Thanks for help

Hans

Answer (score 0):

Tried some things by myself. The result:

It worked when applying this setup:

Haskell installation with:

```
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

yesod installation with:

```
sudo apt-get install yesod
```

Cabal update.

And then continuing as provided in the quick start docu of yesod, yesod init etc etc.

Need to verify this, but at the moment it works, yesod test project compiled and runned nicely.